# php constant case-insensitive issue

Tags: php

I'm overriding a constant with case in-sensitive parameter. But php doesn't give me "constant already defined" error. I've enabled E_ALL,E_STRICT errors.
Example:1

```
define('ONE',1000);
define('one',2000,true);
echo ONE; // prints 1000
echo one; // prints 2000
```

In the second line, i'm making 'one' as another constant with case in-sensitive, which means redefining 'ONE'. But PHP gives no error/warning.

Example:2

```
define('ONE',1000,true);
define('one',2000);
echo ONE; // prints 1000 with constant already defined notice
echo one; // prints 1000
```

Here i can get error notice.

What's the difference between these two code blocks.?

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> Note: Case-insensitive constants are stored as lower-case.

Thus, when trying to define the lower-cased version of the constant in your second example, the constant is already defined due to the prior case-insensensitive definition of a constant with the same name.

```
define('ONE', 1000, true);  // defines strtolower("ONE") = "one"
define('one', 2000);        // error redefining "one"
```

In the first scenario, there is no such collision:

```
define('ONE', 1000);        // defines "ONE"
define('one', 2000, true);  // defines strtolower("one") = "one"
```

Answer (score 0):

The third Parameter in the define function is the case_insensitive option.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.define.php

In the first Example the constant ONE ist defined. And the constant one with case_insensitive  true. Means you got a variable you can reach via ONE and a variable you can reach via oNe,One,oNE etc.

In the secound Example you first define a constant ONE with case_insensitive true and then the constant one. But this time all possible names (OnE,oNe,one) are already given, so the interpreter gives you a error notice

Comment: This almost makes sense.  Unfortunately, it's wrong.  If you switch the two `define`s in the first example (to make the case-insensitive one first), it still shows 1000 and 2000.  If this answer were correct, i should see a notice and two 1000s as in the second example.

Comment: really ? Then I don't get :P

Comment: Eh.  It's PHP weirdness.  Just go with it.  :P  See Niko's answer for an explanation that makes sense if you tilt your head, squint just right, and remember this is still PHP we're talking about here.